# API calling using CodeIgniter famework

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I am getting an error when calling the rest API in postman. please solve the error.
The given error is shown below.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function row() on boolean
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniterRestApi\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 935
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniterRestApi\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
>   Line: 469 Function: _detect_api_key File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniterRestApi\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

REST_Controller.php

```
if ( ! ($row = $this->rest->db->where($this->config->item('rest_key_column'), $key)->get($this->config->item('rest_keys_table'))->row()))
{
    $this->_allow = $this->_detect_api_key();
}
```

Comment: just echo your last_query() and see the issue.

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Just guessing, $row is giving true or false as output because of !($row...).. you need to do something else

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if you didn't have configured your Rest Server properly.

In your case - you set in your `rest.php` config file (you'll find it unter `/application/config/rest.php`) the key `$config['rest_enable_keys']` to `true`, but you didn't create the necessary table for.

if you really want to use keys for your rest service you've to create this/those tables.
this is very well documented in the related config file.

> You can find this information in your file or on github - take a look
>   [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/config/rest.php#L305)

Create Code

```
CREATE TABLE `keys` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `key` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   `level` INT(2) NOT NULL,
   `ignore_limits` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `is_private_key` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `ip_addresses` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_created` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```